# OAuth2 User Credentials Grant Security

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a couple security questions on the OAuth 2.0 User Credential Grant type and possible security attacks. So from what I understand so far, when I exchange my users username password client ID and client secret for an access token over HTTPS that is completely safe. Now say for an example if I have a first party mobile application for a service that is doing the user authentication and I keep the access token on the device.

1. If the access token is compromised some how the compromised access token can be used to make subsequent requests to say for example the API service. Is there any way to prevent this other than just not getting the access token out there?
2. If your doing all API requests over HTTPS I shouldn't have to be worried what so ever about the access token being compromised over the wire or have to worry about any replay attacks?

So basically my concerns about possible security flaws with this specific type of grant. I'm pretty sure if the access token doesn't get compromised and all traffic is over SSL it should be fine.

I'd love to hear someone's expert opinion not the biggest OAuth person.

Answer (score 1):

If the access token is compromised, the app that now has it CAN misuse it. Since access tokens are short lived, and are mapped to certain permissions only - the damage would be limited to say 10 minutes access to a single resource! (tokens are generated for apps that are registered for a scope, the scopes are mapped to permissions.)

If you are working on a first party app, why do you want to store the token on device? You can think of using the authorization code flow and not the implicit grant flow. That way the access token is always with the server and not on the device locally.

Comment: I understand if the access token is compromised the attacker can use it yes. I understand how scopes work. I want to store the access token on the device rather than storing the users password for authentication. I want a native login not a redirect to a webpage to get the access token hence why I am using the password grant.